# How to solve the problem of PyTorch stack?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run Python program using *PyTorch*. How should I make each tensor in batch equal? Because the following problem appears:

> ```py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 311, in <module>
>     fire.Fire(demo)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 138, in Fire
>     component_trace = _Fire(component, args, parsed_flag_args, context, name)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 468, in _Fire
>     target=component.__name__)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\fire\core.py", line 672, in _CallAndUpdateTrace
>     component = fn(*varargs, **kwargs)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 289, in demo
>     n_epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, seed=seed)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 168, in train
>     n_epochs=n_epochs,
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Downloads\efficient_densenet_pytorch-master\demoEmotion.py", line 42, in train_epoch
>     for batch_idx, (input, target) in enumerate(loader):
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 346, in __next__
>     data = self._next_data()
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 386, in _next_data
>     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
>     return self.collate_fn(data)
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 87, in default_collate
>     return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 87, in <listcomp>
>     return [default_collate(samples) for samples in transposed]
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 72, in default_collate
>     return default_collate([torch.as_tensor(b) for b in batch])
>   File "C:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\collate.py", line 63, in default_collate
>     return torch.stack(batch, 0, out=out)
> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [650] at entry 0 and [108] at entry 1
> ```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help